# Magento Sales Order Fixed vs Dynamic Item Price line by line pricing

Tags: php, magento

Trying to figure out how to change the way Magento deals with fixed and dynamic bundle products in the back-end.

Currently with a dynamic bundle the admin panel sales order view shows you a line by line break down of price but with a fixed bundle it only shows you a total price.  Please see the images for a clearer view of the situation.

Dynamic Bundle:

[image]

Fixed Bundle:

[image]

I’d like fixed price bundles to show pricing in the same way as dynamic bundles in the final sales order because when we pull the order from Magento into our accounting software we need line by line pricing for each SKU otherwise it shows the products with a value of $0.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Adam